# SQL query failing for unknown reason

Tags: sql, postgresql

I am trying to achieve the following tutorial : https://dzone.com/articles/automatic-indexes-recommendations-in-postgresql in order to optimize queries on our database.

Upon executing the following function found in the tutorial :

```
CREATE
OR
replace FUNCTION find_usable_indexes()
returns void AS $$DECLARE l_queries RECORD;l_querytext text;l_idx_def text;l_bef_exp text;l_after_exp text;hypo_idx record;l_attr record;
/* l_err int; */BEGIN
  CREATE TABLE
  if not EXISTS PUBLIC.idx_recommendations (queryid bigint, query text, current_plan jsonb, recmnded_index text , hypo_plan jsonb);
  for l_queries IN
  SELECT   t.relid,
           t.relname,
           t.queryid,
           t.attnames,
           t.attnums,
           Pg_qualstats_example_query(t.queryid) AS query
  FROM     (
                    SELECT   qs.relid::regclass AS relname,
                             qs.relid           AS relid,
                             qs.queryid,
                             string_agg(DISTINCT quote_ident(attnames.attnames),',') AS attnames,
                             qs.attnums
                    FROM     pg_qualstats_all qs
                    JOIN     pg_qualstats q
                    ON       q.queryid = qs.queryid
                    JOIN     pg_stat_statements ps
                    ON       q.queryid = ps.queryid
                    JOIN     pg_amop amop
                    ON       amop.amopopr = qs.opno
                    JOIN     pg_am
                    ON       amop.amopmethod = pg_am.oid,
                             lateral
                             (
                                      SELECT   pg_attribute.attname AS attnames
                                      FROM     pg_attribute
                                      JOIN     Unnest(qs.attnums) a(a)
                                      ON       a.a = pg_attribute.attnum
                                      AND      pg_attribute.attrelid = qs.relid
                                      ORDER BY pg_attribute.attnum) attnames,
                             lateral unnest(qs.attnums) attnum(attnum)
                    WHERE    NOT (
                                      exists
                                      (
                                             SELECT 1
                                             FROM   pg_index i
                                             WHERE  i.indrelid = qs.relid
                                             AND    (
                                                           arraycontains((i.indkey::integer[])[0:array_length(qs.attnums, 1) - 1], qs.attnums::integer[])
                                                    OR     arraycontains(qs.attnums::integer[], (i.indkey::integer[])[0:array_length(i.indkey, 1) + 1])
                                                    AND    i.indisunique)))
                    AND      qs.queryid NOT IN (-2862297032983545665)
                    GROUP BY qs.relid,
                             qs.queryid,
                             qs.qualnodeid,
                             qs.attnums) t
  GROUP BY t.relid,
           t.relname,
           t.queryid,
           t.attnames,
           t.attnums
  loop
  /* RAISE NOTICE '% : is queryid',l_queries.queryid; */
  EXECUTE 'explain (FORMAT JSON) '||l_queries.query INTO l_bef_exp;
  EXECUTE 'select hypopg_reset()';
  EXECUTE 'SELECT indexrelid,indexname FROM hypopg_create_index(”CREATE INDEX on '||quote_ident(l_queries.relname::text)||'('||l_queries.attnames||')”)' INTO hypo_idx;
  EXECUTE 'explain (FORMAT JSON) '||l_queries.query INTO l_after_exp;
  EXECUTE 'select hypopg_get_indexdef('||hypo_idx.indexrelid||')' INTO l_idx_def;
  INSERT INTO PUBLIC.idx_recommendations
              (
                          queryid,
                          query,
                          current_plan,
                          recmnded_index,
                          hypo_plan
              )
              VALUES
              (
                          l_queries.queryid,
                          l_querytext,
                          l_bef_exp::jsonb,
                          l_idx_def,
                          l_after_exp::jsonb
              );

ENDLOOP;EXECUTE 'select hypopg_reset()';END;$$ language plpgsql;
```

The following error is being raised :

```
ERROR:  unterminated quoted identifier at or near ""alias_node_test_procedur"
LINE 1: ..."alias_node_test_procedure"."test_units_order" AS "alias_nod...
                                                             ^
QUERY:  explain (FORMAT JSON) SELECT "node"."object_id" AS "node_object_id", "node"."node_id" AS "node_node_id", "node"."start_rev" AS "node_start_rev", "node"."end_rev" AS "node_end_rev", "node"."updated_on" AS "node_updated_on", "node"."lang" AS "node_lang", "node"."second_lang" AS "node_second_lang", "node"."title" AS "node_title", "node"."title_second_lang" AS "node_title_second_lang", "node"."execution_modes" AS "node_execution_modes", "node"."circuit_letters" AS "node_circuit_letters", "node"."root_id" AS "node_root_id", "node"."owner" AS "node_owner", "node"."updated_by" AS "node_updated_by", "node"."main_skill_code" AS "node_main_skill_code", "alias_node_test_procedure"."object_id" AS "alias_node_test_procedure_object_id", "alias_node_test_procedure"."node_id" AS "alias_node_test_procedure_node_id", "alias_node_test_procedure"."start_rev" AS "alias_node_test_procedure_start_rev", "alias_node_test_procedure"."end_rev" AS "alias_node_test_procedure_end_rev", "alias_node_test_procedure"."test_units_order" AS "alias_node_test_procedur
CONTEXT:  PL/pgSQL function find_usable_indexes() line 50 at EXECUTE
SQL state: 42601
```

It seems that the recorded query is truncated for some reason, but I am unsure about this.

Answer (score 0):

the error message gives you the information you need. the context:

```
PL/pgSQL function find_usable_indexes() line 50 at EXECUTE
```

points to the section of the query:

```
FROM     (
                    SELECT   qs.relid::regclass AS relname,
                             qs.relid           AS relid,
                             qs.queryid,
                             string_agg(DISTINCT quote_ident(attnames.attnames),',') AS attnames,
```

Notice that `quote_ident` that is going to wrap the results in "". However, the other part of your error:

```
ERROR:  unterminated quoted identifier at or near ""alias_node_test_procedur"
```

is showing that there is something with two "" on one side, and only one " on the other. So, something in your `attnames.attnames` is named "alias_Node_test_procedur and needs that quote on only one side dealt with.

Comment: Thanks for your help ! Those are queries being analyzed and generated by TypeORM. Do you have any idea where I could start looking at ?

Comment: @MaximeB it looks like `attnames` comes from the part of the query `SELECT   pg_attribute.attname AS attnames
                                      FROM     pg_attribute` so I would suggest running just that level of select, and make sure the output values are valid. I'm not familiar with what that data is, or where it's being used, so I'd suggest getting that info before updating any invalid values.

Comment: Sorry for the delay, the data returned by ```SELECT   pg_attribute.attname AS attnames FROM     pg_attributes ORDER BY pg_attribute.attnum``` is valid. What could be causing such issues with quotes?

Comment: Moreover, ```SELECT   string_agg(DISTINCT quote_ident(pg_attribute.attname),',') AS attnames FROM     pg_attribute``` returns valid data as such : https://pastebin.com/DDNM5qhZ

Comment: It seems that l_queries.query is actually being truncated ? https://pastebin.com/LsWW4w3d

Answer (score 0):

This issue is caused by the `track_activity_query_size` option in Postgres configuration maxing the query size limit returned by `Pg_qualstats_example_query` to 2048 characters. Increasing this value fixes that issue.

Issue is referenced here : https://github.com/powa-team/pg_qualstats/issues/39